# Computer Architect Book Reccomendation

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture

Best Book For Computer Architect , As I have to build SAP this semester.

Most people  told me it is very difficult to make a SimpleAsPossible 8 bit Computer up and running therefore any suggestions for the best book in your view that will make my concepts for this course much strong

Thanks

Comment: "Second Audio Program"? "Shrimp Alkaline Phosphatase"? "Socialist Alternative Politics"? ...

Comment: Sorry about that see the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computer Organization and Design by David A. Patterson and John L. Hennessy is one of the classic sources. If you can understand it, it will help you.